# Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку в регулярном выражении?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Из всех, существующих на страничке ясваскриптов нужно удалить только этот:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ( !page_params.holiday_promo && page_params.zoneDetails.urlAlter != '') {
        var iframes = document.getElementsByClassName('noAdsWhiteListed');
        //var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
        var i = 0;
        var j = iframes.length;
        for (; i < j; i++) {
            var id = iframes[i].id;
            ni = document.createElement('iframe'),
                    parent = iframes[i].parentNode;
            ni.src = page_params.zoneDetails[id]['src'].replace(page_params.zoneDetails.urlToReplace, page_params.zoneDetails.urlAlter);
            ni.id = id;
            ni.className = page_params.zoneDetails[id]['class'];
            ni.style.display = 'block !important';
            ni.style.visibility = 'visible !important';
            ni.style.opacity = 'opacity: 1 !important';
            ni.setAttribute('name', page_params.zoneDetails[id].name);
            ni.setAttribute('scrolling', page_params.zoneDetails[id].scrolling);
            ni.setAttribute('allowtransparency', page_params.zoneDetails[id].allowtransparency);
            ni.setAttribute('marginwidth', page_params.zoneDetails[id].marginwidth);
            ni.setAttribute('marginheight', page_params.zoneDetails[id].marginheight);
            if (!page_params.zoneDetails[id].isResponsive) {
                ni.setAttribute('width', page_params.zoneDetails[id].width);
                ni.setAttribute('height', page_params.zoneDetails[id].height);
            }
            parent.appendChild(ni);
        }
        //remove unnecessary old iframes
        while (iframes.length > 0) {
            iframes[0].parentNode.removeChild(iframes[0]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Обязательное условие, удалить скрипт, к котором будет два паттерна `holiday_promo` и `urlToReplace`, для этого использую регулярное выражение:

```
$buffer = preg_replace("#<script type=\"text/javascript\">[^>]+holiday_promo[^>]+urlToReplace[^>]+</script>#", "", $buffer);
```

где ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам регулярка

```
@<script(?=(?:.(?!</?script))*?holiday_promo)(?=(?:.(?!</?script))*?urlToReplace).*?</script>@s
```

Хотя, считаю не правильным решать эту задачу с помощью регулярок.

Пример тут https://regex101.com/r/kQ3cQ0/1

Comment: работает, супер,спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать так:

```
$buffer = preg_replace("#<script type=\"text/javascript\">[^<]+holiday_promo[^<]+urlToReplace[^<]+</script>#", "", $buffer);
```

В вашем случае поиск идет до конца закрывающего тега.

И еще можно попробовать сделать условия "не жадными".

```
$buffer = preg_replace("#<script type=\"text/javascript\">[^<]+?holiday_promo[^<]+?urlToReplace[^<]+?</script>#", "", $buffer);
```

Как вариант можно воспользоваться preg_replace_callback. Т.е. сначала проходимся по всем тегам скрипт, а внутри callback функции определяем что в теле скрипта есть нужные строки и либо возвращаем пустую строку, либо строку без изменений.

Как-то так:

```
$buffer = preg_replace_callback(
  "#<script.*?</script>#", 
  function($matches) {
    if (stripos($matches[0], "holiday_promo") && stripos($matches[0], "urlToReplace")) {
     return "";
    } 
    return $matches[0];
  },
  $buffer);
```

Comment: попробовал, не работает...

Comment: да, не заметил - у вас там в коде угловые скобки тоже есть...

Comment: `"#<script.*?</script>#"` - может, `"#<script>.*?</script>#"`?

Comment: обязательное условие `<script type="text/javascript">`, то есть нам подходит вариант с `"#<script.*?</script>#"`, но и он не работает :(